# Calculadora Java Script 2

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Problema con la division, en todos los numero que ponga para dividir me da INFINITY y no se donde porque no tengo nada para que me de INFINITY y queria hacer la Calcuradora para que cuando dividas por 0 ponga 0.(Resuelto)

---

Bueno ahora fue al modificarlo que no me sale la alerta que tengo puesta para que de ERROR, y no se si hace el paso del "if", que puse.(Sin Resolver)

Aqui abajo pongo el codigo, que me ayudaron a modificar, para que funcionara en tres pantallas distintas y que el simbolo de operacion, fuera cambiando:

```js
// Modelo de Datos
var operandoa = '';
var operandob = '';
var operacion = '+';
var operadorPulsado = false;

// Vista
var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
var campoOperandoA = document.getElementById("OperA");
var campoOperandoB = document.getElementById("OperB");
var campoOperador = document.getElementById("operac");
var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
var division = document.getElementById("division");
var multiplicacion = document.getElementById("multiplicacion");
var resta = document.getElementById("resta");
var suma = document.getElementById("suma");
var verificar = document.getElementById("verificar");
var uno = document.getElementById("uno");
var dos = document.getElementById("dos");
var tres = document.getElementById("tres");
var cuatro = document.getElementById("cuatro");
var cinco = document.getElementById("cinco");
var seis = document.getElementById("seis");
var siete = document.getElementById("siete");
var ocho = document.getElementById("ocho");
var nueve = document.getElementById("nueve");
var cero = document.getElementById("cero");
var coma = document.getElementById("coma");
var borradoParcial = document.getElementById("borradoParcial");

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Controlador: Se Encarga de Enlazar el Modelo de Datos con la Vista
//------------------------------------------------------------------------

function init() {
  
  //---------------------------------------------
  //Digitos
  //---------------------------------------------
  
  uno.onclick = function(e) {
    funcionalidadBotonNumerico("1");
  };
  dos.onclick = function(e) {
    funcionalidadBotonNumerico("2");
  };
  tres.onclick = function(e) {
    funcionalidadBotonNumerico("3");
  };
  cuatro.onclick = function(e) {
    funcionalidadBotonNumerico("4");
  };
  cinco.onclick = function(e) {
    funcionalidadBotonNumerico("5");
  };
  seis.onclick = function(e) {
    funcionalidadBotonNumerico("6");
  };
  siete.onclick = function(e) {
    funcionalidadBotonNumerico("7");
  };
  ocho.onclick = function(e) {
    funcionalidadBotonNumerico("8");
  };
  nueve.onclick = function(e) {
    funcionalidadBotonNumerico("9");
  };
  cero.onclick = function(e) {
    funcionalidadBotonNumerico("0");
  };
  coma.onclick = function(e) {
    funcionalidadBotonNumerico(".");
  };
  
  //------------------------------------------------
  //Teclas de Función Especial
  //------------------------------------------------
  
  reset.onclick = function(e) {
    resetear();
  };
  borradoParcial.onclick = function(e) {
    funcionBorradoParcial();
  };
  
  //-------------------------------------------------
  // Teclas de Operación
  //-------------------------------------------------
  
  suma.onclick = function(e) {
    botonDeOperacion("+");
  };
  resta.onclick = function(e) {
    botonDeOperacion("-");
  };
  multiplicacion.onclick = function(e) {
    botonDeOperacion("*");
  };
  division.onclick = function(e) {
    botonDeOperacion("/");
  };
  verificar.onclick = function(e) {
    operadorPulsado = false;
    resolver();
  };
}

//---------------------------------------------------

function resetear() {
  operandoa = '';
  operandob = '';
  resultado.textContent = "";
  campoOperandoA.textContent = operandoa;
  campoOperandoB.textContent = operandob;
}

function funcionalidadBotonNumerico(digito){
  if (operadorPulsado) {
    operandob += digito;
    campoOperandoB.textContent = operandob;
  } else {
    operandoa += digito;
    campoOperandoA.textContent = operandoa;
  }
}

function botonDeOperacion(digitooperacion){
  operadorPulsado = true;
  operacion = digitooperacion;
  campoOperador.textContent = operacion;
}

function resolver() {

  var res = "";
  switch (operacion) {
    case "+":
      res = parseFloat(operandoa) + parseFloat(operandob);
      break;
    case "-":
      res = parseFloat(operandoa) - parseFloat(operandob);
      break;
    case "*":
      res = parseFloat(operandoa) * parseFloat(operandob);
      break;
    case "/":
      if (operandob === 0) {
        res = '?';
        window.alert("ERROR: división entre cero");
      } else {
        res = parseFloat(operandoa) / parseFloat(operandob);
      }
      break;
  }
  resetear();
  resultado.textContent = res;
}

function funcionBorradoParcial() {
  if (operadorPulsado) {
    operandob=operandob.slice(0,-1);
    campoOperandoB.textContent = operandob;
  } else {
    operandoa=operandoa.slice(0,-1);
    campoOperandoA.textContent = operandoa;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
  font-size: 22px;
  background: href();
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, #fff 24%, #CCE);
  background-size: cover;
}

#Contenedor {
  width: 290px;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  margin: 4px auto;
}

#calculadora {
  width: 234px;
  height: 230px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #65D277;
}

#operac,
#equal {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 6px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

#OperA,
#OperB,
#resultado {
  float: left;
  /*margin: 8px auto 8px 4px;*/
  margin: 7px -3px 5px 8px;
  width: 25%;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
  color: #48484D;
  /*padding: 4px;*/
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 4px 1px #eee;
}

.Teclas li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6C73FA;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px -3px 5px 8px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px 0px #444651;
}

.Teclas li:hover {
  background-color: #BEF9F0;
  color: #6C73FA;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.Teclas li:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #444651;
}

.verificar {
  width: 93.4% !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Tarea 2.8 - Kepriel</title>
  <link type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <div id="Contenedor">
    <header class="Titulo">
      <h1>Calculadora</h1>
    </header>
    <section id="calculadora">
      <header class="top">
        <div id="OperA"></div>
        <div id="operac">+</div>
        <div id="OperB"></div>
        <div id="equal">=</div>
        <div id="resultado"></div>
      </header>
      <ul class="Teclas">
        <li></li>
        <li id="borradoParcial">DEL</li>
        <li id="reset">C</li>
        <li></li>
        <li id="siete">7</li>
        <li id="ocho">8</li>
        <li id="nueve">9</li>
        <li id="division">&frasl;</li>
        <li id="cuatro">4</li>
        <li id="cinco">5</li>
        <li id="seis">6</li>
        <li id="multiplicacion">*</li>
        <li id="uno">1</li>
        <li id="dos">2</li>
        <li id="tres">3</li>
        <li id="resta">-</li>
        <li id="cero">0</li>
        <li id="coma">.</li>
        <li id="suma">+</li>
        <li id="verificar">=</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calculadora.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuevamente encontré dos errores en tu código, en esta porción:

```
if (operandob = 0){
    return 0;
}
```

en lugar de return deberías guardar el resultado en res, y la comparación de valores debería ser con dos iguales, o sea con ==, algo así:

```
if (operandob == 0){
    res = 0;
}
```

Acá te copio el código modificado.

Saludos.

```js
//Variables
  
  var a;
  var b;
  var c;
  var d;
  var f;

  var operandoa;
  var operandob;
  var operacion;

  var resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
  var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
  var division = document.getElementById("division");
  var multiplicacion = document.getElementById("multiplicacion");
  var resta = document.getElementById("resta");
  var suma = document.getElementById("suma");
  var verificar = document.getElementById("verificar");
  var uno = document.getElementById("uno");
  var dos = document.getElementById("dos");
  var tres = document.getElementById("tres");
  var cuatro = document.getElementById("cuatro");
  var cinco = document.getElementById("cinco");
  var seis = document.getElementById("seis");
  var siete = document.getElementById("siete");
  var ocho = document.getElementById("ocho");
  var nueve = document.getElementById("nueve");
  var cero = document.getElementById("cero");

//Eventos


function init() {
  uno.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "1";
  }
  dos.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "2";
  }
  tres.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "3";
  }
  cuatro.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "4";
  }
  cinco.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "5";
  }  
  seis.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "6";
  }
  siete.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "7";
  }
  ocho.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "8";
  }  
  nueve.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "9";
  }
  cero.onclick = function(e){
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "0";
  }
  
  //--------------------------------------------------
  //Resetear
  //--------------------------------------------------
  
  reset.onclick = function(e){
    resetear();
  }
  
  //--------------------------------------------------
  // Operaciones
  //--------------------------------------------------
  
  suma.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "+";
    limpiar1(a);
  }
  resta.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "-";
    limpiar2(b);
  }
  multiplicacion.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "*";
    limpiar3(c);
  }
  division.onclick = function(e){
    operandoa = resultado.textContent;
    operacion = "/";
    limpiar4(d);
  }
  verificar.onclick = function(e){
    operandob = resultado.textContent.substr(operandoa.length + 1);
    resolver();
  }
}

function limpiar1(a){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "+";
}
function limpiar2(b){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "-";
}
function limpiar3(c){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "*";
}
function limpiar4(d){
  resultado.textContent = operandoa + "/";
}

//------------------------------------------------

function resetear(){
  resultado.textContent = "";
  operandob = 0;
  operandob = 0;
  operacion = "";
}

//------------------------------------------------

function resolver(){
  
  var res = "";
  
  switch(operacion){
    case "+":
      res = parseInt(operandoa) + parseInt(operandob);
      break;
    case "-":
      res = parseInt(operandoa) - parseInt(operandob);
      break;
      case "*":
      res = parseInt(operandoa) * parseInt(operandob);
      break;
      case "/":
      
      if (operandob == 0){
        res = 0;
      } else {
        res = parseInt(operandoa) / parseInt(operandob);
      }
      break;
  }
  resetear();
  resultado.textContent = res;
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
 font-size:22px;
}
li{
 list-style:none;
}
html {
 height: 100%;
 background: white;
 background: radial-gradient(circle, #fff 24%, #CCE);
 background-size: cover;
}
#Contenedor{
 width: 290px;
 text-align: center;
 height:auto;
 margin:4px auto;
}
#calculadora{
 width: 234px;
 height: 230px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:2px;
 background-color: #65D277;
}
#resultado{
 margin:8px auto;
 width:95%;
 height:30px;
 font-size: 16px;
 overflow:hidden;
 text-align: right;
 color:#48484D;
 padding: 4px;
 background-color:#fff;
 box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 4px 1px #eee;
}
.Teclas li{
 width:50px;
 height:30px;
 border-radius:3px;
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#6C73FA;
 cursor:pointer;
 float:left;
 margin: 0px -3px 5px 8px;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px 0px #444651;
}
.Teclas li:hover{
 background-color: #BEF9F0;
 color: #6C73FA;
 transition:0.2s;
}
.Teclas li:active{
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #444651;
}
.verificar{
 width: 93.4% !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Tarea 2.8 - Kepriel</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
 <div id="Contenedor">
  <header class="Titulo">
    <h1>Calculadora</h1>
  </header>
  <section id="calculadora">
   <header class="top">
    <div id="resultado">0</div>
   </header>
   <ul class="Teclas">
        <li></li>
        <li>DEL</li>
        <li id="reset" onclick="init()">C</li>
        <li></li>
    <li id="siete" onclick="init()">7</li>
    <li id="ocho" onclick="init()">8</li>
    <li id="nueve" onclick="init()">9</li>
    <li id="division"onclick="init()">&frasl;</li>
    <li id="cuatro" onclick="init()">4</li>
    <li id="cinco" onclick="init()">5</li>
    <li id="seis" onclick="init()">6</li>
    <li id="multiplicacion" onclick="init()">*</li>
    <li id="uno" onclick="init()">1</li>
    <li id="dos" onclick="init()">2</li>
    <li id="tres" onclick="init()">3</li>
    <li id="resta" onclick="init()">-</li>
    <li id="cero" onclick="init()">0</li>
    <li>.</li>
    <li id="suma" onclick="init()">+</li>
    <li id="verificar" onclick="init()">=</li>
   </ul>
  </section>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calculadora.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias me ayudo bastante.

Comment: me podrias ayudar, es que con las modificaciones que hice no me sale la alerta de Error de la division.